# Double form submit - options on server side

Tags: asp.net, double-submit-prevention

In my ASP.NET application...

I was looking at stopping users double submitting a form by having a token in a hidden field that is compared to a value at the server.

In terms of storing the token at the server side I am not using Session state and the only other place would be the database which I'd rather avoid. Is there anywhere else I couldstore this?

Comment: Ive read this thread http://forums.asp.net/t/447620.aspx/3/10 and it seems the generally accepted solution for this problem is to use the onclick javascript to firstly disable/hide the button and THEN submit the form - this is relatively easy to implement and does prevent a double submission.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to prevent double form-submission.
An example for a button :

```
<asp:Button ID="bt" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
       OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;"  OnClick="bt_Click" />
```